# Usar parámetros DEFAULT en una función

Tags: sql-server

Necesito enviar a mi función (que estoy creando) una serie de parámetros, los cuales en algún momento PUEDEN ser obviados y no ser puestos en la llamada.

```
select * from ESTADO_CUENTA('5', NULL, NULL, '01/01/2019', NULL)

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ESTADO_CUENTA]
    (@Ingenio char(1) ='5',
     @Semana int = 48,
     @Zafra int = 2019,
     @FechaInicio date = '01/01/2019',
     @FechaFinal date = '01/12/2019')

RETURNS @retTablaDatos TABLE
(
    SEMANA INT NOT NULL,
    SAFRA INT NOT NULL,
    PROVEEDOR VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    CONCEPTO VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    NOME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    DESCUENTO INT NOT NULL,
    CONTRA_PARTIDA VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
    ANTERIOR INT NOT NULL,
    CARGO INT NOT NULL,
    ABONO INT NOT NULL,
    ACTUAL INT NOT NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
.
.
.
    )
    INSERT @retTablaDatos
    SELECT SEMANA, SAFRA, PROVEEDOR, CONCEPTO, NOME, DESCUENTO, CONTRA_PARTIDA, ANTERIOR, CARGO, ABONO, ACTUAL FROM Resultado
    RETURN
END;
```

El punto es: Ya tengo valores a usar como base, ¿cómo especificar que POR OMISIÓN o default utilice los parámetros internos a la función en caso que falten?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que usar la palabra clave DEFAULT en el lugar del parámetro.

```
SELECT * 
FROM ESTADO_CUENTA('5', DEFAULT, DEFAULT, '01/01/2019', DEFAULT);
```

Answer (score 1):

Deberías hacerlo así (según [SQL Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)):

```
select * from ESTADO_CUENTA('5', default, default, '01/01/2019', default)
```